# how to move character physics locally amazon lumberyard

Tags: lua, game-engine

I'm having some issues with moving a character physics capsule in local space. No matter what rotation I give it, it still moves in relation to world space. I've attached a mesh component, a character physics component, an input component with my input, and a lua script to it. Here's the movement code in my lua script:

```
function PlayerController:HandleInput(floatValue)
    local currentBusId = InputEventNotificationBus.GetCurrentBusId()

    local forwardSpeed = 0.0
    local sideSpeed = 0.0
    local rotate = 0.0

    local fixedSpeed = self.Properties.Speed * 0.01
    local fixedStrafeSpeed = self.Properties.StrafeSpeed * 0.01

    if(currentBusId == self.forwardBusId) then
        forwardSpeed = floatValue
    end
    if(currentBusId == self.leftBusId) then
        sideSpeed = -floatValue
    end
    if(currentBusId == self.rotateBusId) then
        rotate = floatValue
    end

    PhysicsComponentRequestBus.Event.AddImpulse(self.entityId, Vector3(fixedStrafeSpeed * sideSpeed, fixedSpeed * forwardSpeed, 0.0))
end
```

I was wondering what the best way to move it in local space would be.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to move a character in local space then you will need to compute it based on the orientation of your character. In C++, it would be like:

```
AZ::Transform myLocation;
TransformBus::EventResult(myLocation, GetEntityId(), &TransformBus::Events::GetWorldTM);

const auto q = Quaternion::CreateFromTransform(myLocation);
const Vector3 disp = q * AZ::Vector3::CreateAxisY( 1.f );
myLocation.SetTranslation(myLocation.GetTranslation() + disp);
```